# Windows licensing in multi VM config

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu

I am planning on building a Linux machine, running up to two Windows VM's at once with KVM and Qemu. I am aware that according to Microsoft's licensing I am required to have a license per VM, however I am unaware if I need to have Pro or Home Edition, and whether or not I can use OEM editions.

My use is for applications that Linux doesn't support, I don't want to dual boot either. I'm going to game on the VM, then I'm going to run Visual Studio or other C++ IDE, then I'm going to have some compiler (VS, GCC, clang etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about actual OEM editions (branded BIOS) or system builder editions? With your choosing of the editions I guess you don't have a volume license and/or software assurance? I'm not sure how qemu does its thing but usually gaming in a VM isn't what you want to even try from my experience.

Comment: Use whichever Windows edition will support the software you want to run. I very much doubt that an OEM version will be valid for a VM. Like @Seth, I am dubious about the performance of games in a VM. Also, I am puzzled why you would need **two** Windows VMs in a single host. Have you considered installing Windows on the hardware and Linux in a VM? Not only would you get better games performance, but you could then use a single OEM licence (though you need to check the legal validity of using this on a self-built system).

Comment: I want to utilise virtualisation to avoid windows as much as possible, qemu and kvm has support for pci pass through, meaning the performance decrease sis only noticeable through benchmarks! Furthermore, I'd like two guests, for when I have a guest over, or my girlfriend wants to do stuff, or if I plain need to test software before I install it on the main guest machine